# Struts - No bean found under attribute key

Tags: struts, struts-1, oc4j

I am using Struts version 1.1 on OC4J 10.1.3 and I am trying to add a new action. I have the form and action defined in the `struts-web-config.xml`

```
 <action path="/CJINSearchFindEmployee"
            type="icis.cjin.findcase.CJINSearchFindEmployeeAction"
            scope="request"
            name="cjinFindEmployeeForm"
            validate="false">
    <forward name="show-form" path="icis2.cjin.findemployee.popup"/>
    <forward name="show-results" path="/cjin/findcase/findEmployeeResults.jsp"/>
 </action>
```

If I change the action back to the code from the example that I've copied it renders

```
<html:form action="/CJINSearchFindCase" styleId="cjinSearchFindEmployee">
```

With the following form action I get the exception that follows

```
<html:form action="/CJINSearchFindEmployee" styleId="cjinSearchFindEmployee">

ERROR  (InsertTag.java:920) - ServletException in '/cjin/findcase/findEmployee.jsp': No bean found under attribute key cjinFindCaseForm
javax.servlet.ServletException: No bean found under attribute key cjinFindCaseForm
    at com.evermind.server.http.EvermindPageContext.handlePageThrowable(EvermindPageContext.java:899)
    at com.evermind.server.http.EvermindPageContext.handlePageException(EvermindPageContext.java:816)
    at _cjin._findcase._findCaseResults._jspService(_findCaseResults.java:780)
    at com.orionserver.http.OrionHttpJspPage.service(OrionHttpJspPage.java:59)
    at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspPageTable.service(JspPageTable.java:473)
    at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspServlet.internalService(JspServlet.java:594)
    at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:518)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ResourceFilterChain.doFilter(ResourceFilterChain.java:64)
    at oracle.security.jazn.oc4j.JAZNFilter.doFilter(JAZNFilter.java:440)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.invoke(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:644)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.unprivileged_include(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:177)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.access$000(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:68)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher$1.oc4jRun(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:114)
    at oracle.oc4j.security.OC4JSecurity.doPrivileged(OC4JSecurity.java:284)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.include(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:119)
    at com.evermind.server.http.EvermindPageContext.include(EvermindPageContext.java:456)
    at _cjin._findcase._findEmployee._jspService(_findEmployee.java:513)
    at com.orionserver.http.OrionHttpJspPage.service(OrionHttpJspPage.java:59)
    at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspPageTable.compileAndServe(JspPageTable.java:735)
    at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspPageTable.service(JspPageTable.java:425)
    at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspServlet.internalService(JspServlet.java:594)
    at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:518)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ResourceFilterChain.doFilter(ResourceFilterChain.java:64)
    at oracle.security.jazn.oc4j.JAZNFilter.doFilter(JAZNFilter.java:440)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.invoke(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:644)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.unprivileged_include(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:177)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.access$000(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:68)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher$1.oc4jRun(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:114)
    at oracle.oc4j.security.OC4JSecurity.doPrivileged(OC4JSecurity.java:284)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.include(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:119)
    at com.evermind.server.http.EvermindPageContext.include(EvermindPageContext.java:456)
    at com.evermind.server.http.EvermindPageContext.include(EvermindPageContext.java:409)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtilImpl.doInclude(TilesUtilImpl.java:101)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtil.doInclude(TilesUtil.java:137)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doInclude(InsertTag.java:758)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag$InsertHandler.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:890)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:460)
    at _cjin._cjinPopUp._jspService(_cjinPopUp.java:150)
    at com.orionserver.http.OrionHttpJspPage.service(OrionHttpJspPage.java:59)
    at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspPageTable.service(JspPageTable.java:473)
    at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspServlet.internalService(JspServlet.java:594)
    at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:518)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ResourceFilterChain.doFilter(ResourceFilterChain.java:64)
    at oracle.security.jazn.oc4j.JAZNFilter.doFilter(JAZNFilter.java:440)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.invoke(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:644)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.forwardInternal(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:391)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.unprivileged_forward(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:280)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.access$100(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:68)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher$2.oc4jRun(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:214)
    at oracle.oc4j.security.OC4JSecurity.doPrivileged(OC4JSecurity.java:284)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.forward(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:219)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1056)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:261)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processTilesDefinition(TilesRequestProcessor.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(TilesRequestProcessor.java:300)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:231)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1164)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:397)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:743)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ResourceFilterChain.doFilter(ResourceFilterChain.java:64)
    at oracle.security.jazn.oc4j.JAZNFilter.doFilter(JAZNFilter.java:440)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.invoke(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:644)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.forwardInternal(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:391)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.doProcessRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:908)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.processRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:458)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.serveOneRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:226)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.run(HttpRequestHandler.java:127)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.run(HttpRequestHandler.java:116)
    at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketReadHandler$SafeRunnable.run(ServerSocketReadHandler.java:260)
    at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketAcceptHandler.procClientSocket(ServerSocketAcceptHandler.java:234)
    at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketAcceptHandler.access$700(ServerSocketAcceptHandler.java:29)
    at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketAcceptHandler$AcceptHandlerHorse.run(ServerSocketAcceptHandler.java:879)
    at com.evermind.util.ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor$MyWorker.run(ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor.java:303)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

Comment: can u post your `findEmployee.jsp` and your action form `cjinFindEmployeeForm`?

Comment: I'd assume you're screwing up the form tag and/or form bean definition and/or form bean name.

Comment: Thanks @DaveNewton and Vinoth Krishnan I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

There was a page included calling the cjinFindCaseForm in the findEmployee.jsp, once I updated this it began to work.

```
<div id="searchResults">
    <jsp:include page="findEmployeeResults.jsp"/>
</div>
```

Thanks for all your help!